# How can I update the values of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to add the value of each key in each dictionary with the value in each list.

```
D = [{1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 
10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 
10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 
10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}]
C = [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 
2], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]]

for c in C:
    for cdx in range(0, len(c)):
        key = cdx + 1
        value = c[cdx]
        for d in D:
            cu_val = d.get(key)
            up_val = cu_val + value
            d[key] = up_val
        print(D)
```

The list of dictionaries and the list of lists are of equal length. Do I want to update the dictionary by adding it value to the value of the list in the same corresponding position.

Comment: The end result of `D` should be `[{1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 11}, ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, the following code should do it:

```
for c, d in zip(C, D):
    for idx, val in enumerate(c):
        d[idx+1] += val
print(D)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** 
This should solve your purpose :)

```
D = [{1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 
10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 
10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 
10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}, {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10}]

C = [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 
2], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]]

for d, c in zip(D, C):
    for key, val in d.items():
        d[key] = val + c.pop()

print(D)
```

**Output:**

```
[{1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 11}, {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 11}, {1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 12}, {1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 13}, {1: 12, 2: 11, 3: 11}, {1: 12, 2: 11, 3: 11}, {1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 11}, {1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 11}, {1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 11}, {1: 13, 2: 11, 3: 11}, {1: 12, 2: 11, 3: 12}, {1: 12, 2: 11, 3: 12}, {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 12}, {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 12}, {1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 12}, {1: 11, 2: 13, 3: 11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
l1 = len(D) #number of dictionary
l2 = len(D[0]) # number of element of dictionary

for i in range(l1):
    for j in range(l2):
        D[i][j+1] += C[i][j]
        
print(D)
```